# Failing to fetch data | Only affects mobile | Express / Postgres / Vue

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, vue.js

My Vue app runs perfectly on desktop, but on mobile, it fails to fetch data when the app loads, leaving the components rendering but with no data to display.

- [Link to the app](https://plantme.herokuapp.com/#/plant-size)
- [Link to the entire Github repository](https://github.com/Am4nzi/plantme)

I diagnosed the issue by running it through Google's Mobile-Friendly Test tool: [here are the results](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly?view=fetch-info&id=7_nc1h_9KWshsdKVJ4bBag).

My `index.js` looks like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const serveStatic = require("serve-static");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const db = require("./queries");

const app = express();
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/dist"));

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/sizemenudata", db.getSizeMenuData);

app.get("/lightlevelmenudata", db.getLightLevelMenuData);

app.get("/easeofcaremenudata", db.getEaseOfCareMenuData);

app.get("/petsafemenudata", db.getPetSafeMenuData);

app.get("/menuTitles", db.getMenuTitles);

app.use(express.static("dist"));

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on ${port}`);
});
```

Things to note:

- I'm fetching the data from a postgres database, [here is my sql file](https://github.com/Am4nzi/plantme/blob/master/sql/plants.sql).
- I have a seperate [queries.js](https://github.com/Am4nzi/plantme/blob/a5fda17ab6f011df63ecb3134a4dd978d7b757d0/queries.js#L10) file which I import into [index.js](https://github.com/Am4nzi/plantme/blob/master/index.js).

Comment: I visited your app, and when I went to the console, it had 9 errors due to the issue that you hardcoded the URL: http://localhost:3000

Comment: For some reason I wasn't receiving the errors, but ultimately you are right, I forgot to set the ENV vars for Heroku. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this because it was a simple error, the Heroku ENV vars weren't set.